# Using one entity in multiple controllers

Tags: symfony, interface, doctrine, entities

The situations' setup is like this:

1) I have two bundles in which I would like to use the same entity. So as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206201/doctrine2-symfony2-multiple-entities-on-same-table) and then in [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html), I created the CommonEntitiesBundle where the desired Entity lives.

2) Then I described the model interface in both bundles I want to use the Entity in. So far so good.

Now I would like to use the interfaced Entity, just like I would use a 'bundle-native' one like this:

```
$clientData = new Client(); // the Entity class
$client->setName('Greg');
```

How should I approach it when there is only the interface available?

I `use`d the interface in this controller.

In the Symfony's example there is only a use of the class via the ORM annotations.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is not a class. it is instead a list of minimal necessary methods a class with 'implements [interfaceName]' must have.

Instead you could provide a example class with your bundle and use that one by default. Add configuration in app/config.yml where you can change the classname. each derived class must implement the interface for consistence.

Comment: So do you mean that, other than for making orm dependencies' the whole `resolve_target_entities` is not needed here? And I can just put two exact same entities in two bundles, that eventually use the same one table in the db?

Comment: i am still not sure what you try to reach. In each case you can use straightforward every entity in every bundle and from every other bundle.

Comment: The goal is to use the same data, through an entity, in two different bundles. I wasn't aware you just do it straight forward. Confirm me that and I'm good to go.